# How to Handle Basic Authentication Pop Up using testRigor

Tags: basic-authentication, testrigor

I need to perofrm some test for one website, but without vpn site requires Basic Authentication. How do i handle this using testRigor.

I looking for some setting where i can pass basic auth credentail details to bypass this step.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Settings->Authentication, you can find the fields to add the credentials for Basic/Digest HTTP Authentication. If you add your credentials to those fields, testRigor will automatically do the basic authentication login for you. This works best when the site that requires basic authentication is the landing page URL set in the Test Suite Details section.